# Обработка строк с помощью курсора

Tags: sql, база-данных, postgresql, plpgsql

Всем здравствуйте!
Есть такое задание:
создать связанный с простым запросом курсор и использовать цикл для перемещения по нему MOVE и в теле цикла менять каждую четную строку и удалять каждую нечетную.
Вот собственно затык на четной/нечетной строке.

```
DO $$
declare
curs1 scroll cursor for select * from shant."All school staff" /*for update*/;
rec record;
begin
    for rec in curs1 
    loop
then
    move from curs1;
    raise notice '%', rec;
    end loop;
end;
$$
```

Если после move ставлю 1 - то выводятся все четные строки. Как вот вывести все нечетные и сделать UPDATE и DELETE согласно условия задачи?

Answer (score 0):

Решил сам. Приведу сначала код:

```
DO $$
    declare
    curs1 cursor for select * from shant."All school staff" order by "Passport ID" for update;
    rec record;
    temps int;
    temps2 int;
    begin
    open curs1;
                for temps2 in reverse 2..1
                loop

                    for temps in temps2..6 by 2
                    loop

                        if (mod (temps,2) <> 0 ) then
                            move absolute 1 from curs1;
                            exit when not found;
                            raise notice '%, odd', temps;
                            UPDATE shant."All school staff" SET "Male" = 'DEL' WHERE CURRENT of curs1;
                        end if;

                        if (mod (temps,2) = 0 ) then
                            move absolute temps from curs1;
                            exit when not found;
                            raise notice '%, even', temps;
                            UPDATE shant."All school staff" SET "Male" = 'ИЗМ' WHERE CURRENT of curs1;
                        end if;

                    end loop;
                end loop;
            close curs1;
    end;
    $$
```

Описание:
перестановку курсора делает move. После move указывается его направление. В моем случае absolute temps, где temps переменная вложенного цикла for. В моей таблице всего 6 строк, взял поэтому числа. Если строк много, то можно через count(*) найти общее количество строк.
Далее в каждом блоке if проверяю сначала на нечетность, потом на четность. В блоках же двигаю курсор и меняю строки. Была замечена проблема "пропадания" строки, если в блоке четных строк использовать UPDATE. При использовании UPDATE в блоке нечетных строк все срабатывало правильно. Решил установкой направления в блоке нечетных строк - absolute 1.
Внешний цикл нужен для установки первой строки. Направление перебора от 2 до 1 или от 1 до 2 влияет лишь на то, какие строки будут выведены первыми (четные или нечетные).
Так как select за каждый вызов "перемешивает" строки, нужно применить сортировку order by.